# Excel Substring between two characters (one of which is second instance)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have the following string:

```
AA_Foo_Bar - ABC123.blah.com
```

I want to retrieve `Bar`. i.e. the text between the second underscore and the space following that underscore.

I have this but it's not quite correct (where A2 is the value):

```
=MID(A2, SEARCH("_",A2) + 1, SEARCH("_",A2,SEARCH("_",A2,)+1) - SEARCH(" ",A2) - 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Answer

```
=MID(A1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_",CHAR(1),2))+1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1," -",CHAR(1),1))-FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_",CHAR(1),2)))
```

## Explanation

First find the index of the second underscore (Answer = 7)

```
=FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_",CHAR(1),2))
```

Next find the index of the first instance of space + dash (`" '"`) (Answer = 11):

```
=FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1," -",CHAR(1),1))
```

Now grab the string from the first index (+1 to chop off the underscore) which means:

```
=MID(A1,7+1,11-7)
```

Now just replace `7` with `FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_",CHAR(1),2))` and `11` with `FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1," -",CHAR(1),1))` and Bob's your Mother's Brother.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1," - ","_"),"_","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[3]")
```

A little less elegant (IMO) could be:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1," - ","_"),"_",REPT(" ",100)),200,100))
```